# Ruby Regex for 1 or two Digit Match with Elsif

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to use the following regexp in ruby

```
<% elsif entry.name=~(/^[0-9][0-9]/) %>
```

to check the entry.name string for a 1 or more digit number.
I can't seem to get the syntax right.

For example I want the statement to return true on a string such as 
"10 Content Creation Mistakes To Avoid At All Costs"

Comment: Use `/^\d+/` instead of `/^[0-9][0-9]/`

Answer (score 4):

A 1 or 2 digit match would be:

```
/^\d{1,2}/
```

To ensure there's not a 3rd digit you can use a lookahead:

```
/^\d{1,2}(?!\d)/
```

Some people mentioned:

```
/^\d+/
```

But that would actually match 3 digits (for example).

Answer (score 1):

What you are matching by `^[0-9][0-9]` is a string which at the beginning of each line (`^`) has exactly two digits from 0 to 9 (`[0-9][0-9]`).

That will match strings as

```
"10 mistakes to avoid at all cost"
```

But also:

```
"Jenny was certain she had\n10 lipsticks"
```

Because it searches digits at the beginning of each line. It won't match

```
"5 mistakes to avoid at all cost"
```

Because it matches exactly to digits.

I think what you want is along the lines of `\A\d+`. `\A` searches only at the beginning of the string and not at each line, `\d+` searches for one or more occurrences of a digit. This will match the following:

```
"3 questions you should be able to answer when doing a job interview"
"345 lines of unreadable code"
"35 kittens"
```

And so on. So your code should read, minus superfluous brackets and plus some spacing:

```
<% elsif entry.name =~ /\A\d+/ %>
```

[rubular](http://rubular.com/) may come in handy next time

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "10 Content Creation Mistakes To Avoid At All Costs"
s.scan(/^\d+/)
# => ["10"]
s.scan(/^\d+/).empty?
# => false
!s.scan(/^\d+/).empty?
# => true

s = "10 Content Creation Mistakes To Avoid At All Costs"
s =~ (/^\d+/)
# => 0
```